# How to display currency symbol using Javascript and Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am in the process of learning Angular and am having trouble displaying a currency symbol.

I am calling my data from an api which is returning a formatted entry like this:

```
"currency_formatted": "&#xa3;20 Million"
```

In angular when I populate the formatted field: {{currency_formatted}} it outputs:

```
 &#xa3;20 Million
```

What I am expecting is: **£20 Million**

I can have the currency symbol returned in the api so: GBP, is there a way to use this to have the correctly formatted currency instead of passing the hex?

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: yeah it was a type, seems SO formats the hex correctly, I have put it into a code snippet so that it shows as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The hex is an HTML-encoded value. You can HTML decode using the `ng-bind-html` directive, for example:

```
<span ng-bind-html="amount"></span>
```

This needs to be sanitized to prevent exploits. To do so, you would need to add a dependency on `'ngSanitize'`, or use `$sce` to trust this as HTML:

```
$scope.amount = $sce.trustAsHtml("&#xa3;20 Million");
```

===

If, however, you can structure your amount into nominal value and currency symbol:

```
$scope.amount = {value: 20000000, symbol: '£'};
```

then you could is to use the `currency` filter to display the amount:

```
<span>{{amount.value | currency: amount.symbol:0}}</span>
```

This will display `"£20,000,000"` - not `"£20 Million"` (so, may not be what you need)

Answer (score 0):

## AngularJS

You could just have the following in your HTML, taking advantage of the filter directive:

```
<div>
   <span>{{ amount | currency : '£' }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem with this one, I do not have the pound sign to hand, only the unicode value... to go this route I would need to update an entire currency table...

Comment: Angular will represent a unicode value as the appropriate character once compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out with the help of a friend and with New Dev's answer above. This is what I have done:

In my HTML:

```
<span ng-bind-html="currency_formatted | safeHtml"></span>
```

Then in my app I wrote a custom filter:

```
//Filter to use html from the api
app.filter('safeHtml', function($sce) {
    return function(unsafeHtml) {
        console.log(unsafeHtml);
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(unsafeHtml);
    }
})
```

Now this returns the html to be inserted into the page.

What was happening before was that Angular was sanitizing the result and escaping the & sign...

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a filter using `toLocaleString` like :

```
Number(data).toLocaleString('en', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR', maximumFractionDigits: 0})
```

Filter example :

```
.filter('EuroCurrency', function() {
    return function(data) {
        if (null != data) {
            return Number(data).toLocaleString('en', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR', maximumFractionDigits: 0});
        } else {
            return Number(0).toLocaleString('en', { style: 'currency',currency: 'EUR', maximumFractionDigits: 0});
        }
    };
});
```

Usage :

```
{{ rent | EuroCurrency }}
```